# NoReverseMatch django 1.4 admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls, django-1.4

I migrated a project from 1.1 to 1.2, then to 1.3, all of this, flawlessly. However, when I moved the version up to 1.4, I keep getting a

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/<app_name>/<model_name>/
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found.
```

All other admin functionality seems to work fine, but every time I try to see a list, I get this NoReverseMatch error.

My url entry for the admin is:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Here's my traceback:

```
Template error:
In template /home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 44
   Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found.
   34 : </script>


   35 : {% endif %}{% endif %}


   36 : {% endblock %}


   37 : 


   38 : {% block bodyclass %}change-list{% endblock %}


   39 : 


   40 : {% if not is_popup %}


   41 : {% block breadcrumbs %}


   42 : <div class="breadcrumbs">


   43 : <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>


   44 : &rsaquo; <a href=" {% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=cl.opts.app_label %} ">{{ app_label|capfirst|escape }}</a>


   45 : &rsaquo; {{ cl.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}


   46 : </div>


   47 : {% endblock %}


   48 : {% endif %}


   49 : 


   50 : {% block coltype %}flex{% endblock %}


   51 : 


   52 : {% block content %}


   53 :   <div id="content-main">


   54 :     {% block object-tools %}


Traceback:
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  136.                     response = response.render()
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  104.             self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  281.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ibustama/yalea/env-yalea/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  424.                         raise e

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /admin/auth/user/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found.
```

Comment: It seems that you've forgot to include one app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` configuration. Did you follow [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site) steps to use the admin pages?

Comment: Hi thanks, I did follow those steps. I thought that maybe I missed some new default apps on the settings file, and even checked  the order. The problem remained the same. Anyways, I found the problem (and it was rather dumb), so I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was rather dumb in the end. One of my custom context processors redefined the "cl" context var, therefore making the following tag fail:

```
{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=cl.opts.app_label %}
```

I just had to make some changes to my own context processor and templates (and employ better context processor var names).

Note: I don't know why this hadn't bothered me before. It should have been a problem even in 1.1, in theory.